# How to push objects to an array in Vue 3 while i < 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, vuejs3

I am attempting to set up a button function in Vue 3 that handles pushing objects to an array in a for loop, while i < 5:

```
const addFeatureObjs = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // featureObjArray.value.push({ id: null, feature: null })
    featureObjArray.value[i] = { id: null, feature: null }
  }
}
```

So far, I have a for loop set up to create 5 instances of the object while i < 5. However, I wish to set up this function so that each button click call to `addFeatureObjs` creates a new object one click at a time until 5 are created, instead of calling `addFeatureObjs` to create the 5 objects all at once. How can I go about setting up this function, for loop, and array to enable creating each object one at a time, until 5 are created?

Comment: you would not need a for loop if each button press creates a single item - just create function `addFeatureObj = () => featureObjArray.value.push({ id: null, feature: null });` ... and call it on click ...

Comment: Ah ok. If I use ```featureObjArray.value.push({ id: null, feature: null })``` instead, how can I prevent the user from adding more than 5 objects to the array?

Comment: before pushing, test length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the array before pushing:

```js
const addFeatureObjs = () => {
  if (featureObjArray.value.length <= 5) {
    featureObjArray.value.push({ id: null, feature: null });
  }
}
```